# CakePHP HABTM find ... not returning expected results

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm hoping somebody can clear up this issue I am having.  None of the other answers on SO seemed to help me out for some reason.

I have 2 tables with a HABTM relationship.  Publications have many authors, and authors have many publications.  In my case, I am attempting to output a list of all of the publications in the database, along with their corresponding authors.

I have the following tables:

### publications:

### id              title

0               TestPublication

### authors:

### id           firstname           lastname           middle

0            John                Doe                A

### authors_publications:

### id          author_id           publication_id

0           0                   0

The 'id' column of each table is set as the primary key.

My Publication model looks like:

```
class Publication extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Publication';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Author'=>array(
            'className'=>'Author'
        )
    );     
}
```

And finally, the PublicationsController has the following function:

```
function index() {
$publications = $this->Publication->find('all');
$this->set('publications', $publications);
}
```

Here is what publications now contains:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Publication] => Array ( [id] => 0 [title] => TestPublica [type_id] => 1 ) [Author] => Array ( ) ) )
```

Why is this?  I am expecting (perhaps that is my problem...) that the author John Doe should be present in the Author array.  If it should be, where am I going wrong?  Do I need a bindModel call somewhere in there?

Or...is the code actually executing the way it should and my expectations are incorrect?  If so, how would I return a list of all of the publications along with all of their authors?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It looks like the db tables were not output as I expected them to be.  Just so it is clear, the publications table contains the values (0, TestPublication), the authors table contains the values (0, John, Doe, A), and the authors_publications table contains the values (0, 0, 0).

Comment: Have you got a similar HABTM relationship set up in your Author model?

Comment: Yes I sure do: class Author extends AppModel {
     
     var $name = 'Author';
  
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
         'Publication'=>array(
             'className'=>'Publication'
         )
     );  
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the problem.  I was manually inserting records into the DB for testing purposes.  I set the primary key id's on the first record of each table to zero.  SQL DBs typically (or always?) start the first record with a primary key index of 1, not 0.  I'm not sure WHY cake did not work with this, but changing the id's to 1 solved the problem.  Weird...